# 'Hour' - wrong parameters count - mql4

Tags: mql4, mt4

I am attempting to restrict the hours during which trading can occur, but I have not been successful with my attempts so far. I would appreciate any input or suggestions on how to accomplish this.

```
// Function to Check if Trade Time is Valid
bool IsTradeTime() {
    datetime now = TimeCurrent();
    int hour = Hour(now);
```

Error: 'Hour' - wrong parameters count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Global Variable
input string baslangicZamani= "08:00";
input string bitisZamani="23:00";
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool ZamanFiltresi()
  {
   datetime _mevcutZaman = TimeCurrent();
   datetime _zamanIlk = StringToTime(TimeToString(_mevcutZaman,TIME_DATE) + " " + baslangicZamani);
   datetime _zamanSon = StringToTime(TimeToString(_mevcutZaman,TIME_DATE) + " " + bitisZamani) + 60;
   if(_zamanIlk>_zamanSon)
     {
      if(_mevcutZaman >= _zamanIlk || _mevcutZaman <= _zamanSon)
         return (true);
      else
         return (false);
     }
   if(_zamanIlk<_zamanSon)
     {
      if(_mevcutZaman >= _zamanIlk && _mevcutZaman <= _zamanSon)
         return (true);
      else
         return (false);
     }
   return (false);
  }
```

Comment: if(ZamanFiltresi()) {buy and sell}